# Change Dart embedded web server port

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-pub

I want to create a web application with dart. 
First of all there is the html:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dart.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="application/dart" src="dart.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dart</h1>

    <p>Hello world from Dart!</p>

    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <table id="table">
        <tr>
          <td>Benutzername:</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="inputuser" maxlength="40"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Passwort:</td>
          <td><input type="password" id="inputpass" maxlength="40"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button id="button"></button></td>
        </tr>  
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my dart file i want to connect to a servlet, which runs on a local glassfish server

The dart file looks like this:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

final TableElement table = querySelector('#table');
final DivElement main_div = querySelector('#sample_container_id');

void main() {
  TextInputElement user = querySelector('#inputuser');
  PasswordInputElement password = querySelector('#inputpass');
  ButtonElement button = querySelector('#button');
  button.text = 'Send';
  button.onClick.listen((e) => checkUser(user, password));
}

void checkUser(TextInputElement user, PasswordInputElement password)
{
  var url = 'http://localhost:8080/dartTestServlet';
  HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", url);
  request.onLoadEnd.listen((e) => onUserChecked(request.response.toString()));

  String jsonData = '{"user":"' + user.value + '", "password":"' + password.value + '"}';

  request.send(jsonData);
}
```

If dart connect to the server i got this error message:

```dart
Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3030' is therefore not allowed access.   http://localhost:8080/dartTestServlet
```

I know that the problem is the same origin policy, but i dont know how to fix it.

I'm using an eclipse instance for the server and a Dart Editor instance for the client. How can i change the port of the embedded web server in the Dart Editor to 8080?

Should i fix this problem otherwise?

Thanx for help in advance.

Comment: That wouldn't fix the problem, as two servers can't use the same port. You have to either serve the dart page via your GlassFish server, or use CORS.

Comment: Thx.
I served the page via Glassfish. This solved the CORS "problem".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the DartEditor but you can use `pub serve --port 8080` or just `pub serve` (8080 is default) from within your package directory.

The web server integrated in DartEditor will be replaced by `pub serve` probably soon.